# C - operations on bits representing a structure

Tags: c, hash, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to write hashset in C, and I've found one hash function, that hashes according to bits in data. I have the following structure:

```
struct triple
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};
```

The question is - how to get bit representation from object of type `struct triple`? Let's say I want to XOR its bits with 8-bit integer. How would I do that?

Comment: Whilst it may seem desirable to have a generic hashing algorithm that can be used for just about everything (in this case, a `triple` as you call it), there's something quite wrong with this idea. Consider that some implementations might employ the idea of *padding bits* in the form of parity checks. If a value byte is followed by a parity byte formed simply by flipping all of the bits, then what use will this hashing algorithm serve? To clarify: In this scenario, all values will yield the same hash, which comprises solely of `1` bits.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour I've never seen a C compiler produce code to maintain checksums.  But nearly every one uses pad _bytes_ for memory alignment. These bytes don't have deterministic values, so - as you said - a hash that includes them is completely unreliable.

Comment: @Gene Ahh, an even better example!

Comment: I've yet to see a compiler that will introduce any padding into a structure with multiple elements of a single type, as in this question.  Technically, a compiler is allowed to add padding; in practice, no compiler will.  However, in structures with diverse element types, padding will be added where necessary — and then the indeterminacy of the padding is a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterate over all the bytes of the `struct` and XOR each one individually, e.g.,

```
void bytexor(unsigned char xor_byte, void *data, size_t size) {
    unsigned char *p = data;
    while (size--) {
        *p++ ^= xor_byte;
    }
}
```

Usage would be:

```
struct triple my_struct;
// ...
bytexor(0xFF, &my_struct, sizeof my_struct);
```

(Note: This answers the question of how to XOR the `struct` with a byte. As for implementing a general hash function based on this, it may not be a particularly good idea since a `struct` may have padding, i.e., extra bytes with potentially non-deterministic values unrelated to the values of the actual payload fields.)